# Why does XCode randomly connect to Facebook and download data?

Tags: xcode

My XCode connects to "**static.ak.facebook.com.edgesuite.net**" and downloads something off there.

Does anyone know what might be causing that behaviour?

Comment: It wastes tons of bandwidth by doing that

Comment: Try getting little snitch and see what's being downloaded.

Comment: Did you add any facebook connect documentation to xcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emailed apple.

**Apparently it is downloading documentation**

Comment: …and they think it's okay to just automatically do that… (To those looking to disable it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qrteJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the activity window.

Under Window > Activity.